# How to find Closest Facility (euclidean distance)?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, distance, network-analyst

I have some facilities and incidents, and I want to find the closest facility for each incident. I've done it via Network Analyst (with a network dataset) but I'm wondering if you can do it with just Euclidean distance). I'm using ArcInfo 10.0.

Answer (score 6):

If your facilities and incidents are both feature layers, and you only care about finding the closest (and not 2nd closest, 3rd closest, etc.) then you can just run [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000). Set your incidents as the `target_features`, facilities as `join_features`, and `closest` as the `match_option`, and it will join the attributes of the nearest facility to each incident.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That did the trick (had to do it via python as default Spatial Join kept on crashing due to a memory leak).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Near Geoprocessing Tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001q000000.htm) to find only the nearest point and not the 2nd or 3rd nearest point.